# React не может найти модуль

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

У меня имеется один класс `CheckboxInput` и один компонент `Login`. Хранятся они в одной папке в разных файлах. И проблема в том, что я не могу использовать `CheckboxInput` в компоненте Login.

`CheckboxInput.jsx`:

```
    CheckboxInput = React.createClass({
        //Тут рабочий код. Если я объявляю это в Login, то всё работает.
    });
    export default CheckboxInput;
```

Ни один из перечисленных ниже вызовов не работает.

`Login`:

```
var CheckboxInput = require('CheckboxInput');
import {CheckboxInput} from 'CheckboxInput';
import CheckboxInput from 'CheckboxInput';
```

Вот что выдает при запуске:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './CheckboxInput.jsx'           module.js:340
i @ babel.min.js:23
```

Что не так? Что нужно сделать?

**Обновление**

`webpack.config.js` :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackTargetElectronRenderer = require('webpack-target-electron-renderer');
var config = {
    //entry: [ 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&path=http://localhost:9000/__webpack_hmr', './src/index', ],
    entry: [ './main.js'],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader'],
            exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.png|\.svg$/,
                loaders: ['file-loader'] },
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }]
    },
    resolve:
        {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        },
    plugins:
        [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new NpmInstallPlugin({
            dev: function(module, path) {
                return [
                        "babel-preset-react-hmre",
                        "webpack-dev-middleware",
                        "webpack-hot-middleware",
                    ].indexOf(module) !== -1;
            },
        })
        ]
};
config.target = webpackTargetElectronRenderer(config);
module.exports = config;
```

**Обновление №2**

Если пытаюсь так:

```
var CheckboxInput = require(__dirname+'\\Components\\CheckboxInput.jsx');
```

То выводит такую ошибку:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import file:
```

Исправляю импорт на это:

```
"use strict";
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

В дальнейшем выводит это:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

то есть уже не понимает функцию render():

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
                style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
                name={this.props.name}
                checked={this.state.checked}
                onChange={this.handleClick}
                value={this.props.value} />
        {this.props.label}
        </label>
    );
},
```

Comment: import CheckboxInput from './Checkbox.jsx'

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky К сожалению не работает.

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky Если импортировать так: var CheckboxInput = require(__dirname+'\\Components\\CheckboxInput.jsx') , то выходит другая ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: Там вместо Checkbox.jsx должно быть CheckboxInput.jsx. Я неверно написал. У вас также написано имя файла из которого импортируется класс?

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky я не скопировал ваш ответ, а просто сделал по подобию. Не работало.

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky import и require наверняка работают, раз могу использовать React и electron-config. Почему такое происходит?

Comment: после import добавьте console.log на эту переменную и посмотрите что возвращает

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky К сожалению это невозможно посмотреть, поскольку приложение не идет дальше этого import. Я только что попробовал так:  import CheckboxInput from './CheckboxInput.jsx';
console.log(CheckboxInput);  И выводит только сообщение о ошибке.

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky Обновил ошибку в вопросе.

Comment: Когда я запускаю через webpack в ошибке содержится путь по которому он ищет модуль. Если импорт работает для Реакта, значит остается неверный путь.

Comment: конфиг вебпака в студию (или чо у вас там)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Добавил.

Comment: короче готов поспорить что конфиг вебпака кривой. Предлагаю вам написать его самому осмысленно. И я по-прежнему считаю что babel-loader у вас настроен неправильно как и вся секция loaders.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Я бы с радостью сам написал, да вот только я ничего в этом пока не понимаю, а нормального туториала не видел.

Comment: @AynurSibagatullin Вы используете слишком много новых для себя технологий сразу (причем ни одной не понимаете) и надеетесь что кто-то разберется в вашем зоопарке за вас. Если протекает один слой абстракции то удаленно отлаживать можно, если несколько - это довольно сложно, потому что вы можете ошибиться в двух десятках мест и пытаться понять в каком именно (а скорее в нескольких сразу) довольно долго. Заставьте работать хоть какой-нибудь кусок а не все в связке.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Вопрос. А можно обойтись только babel-ом, без использования webpack?

Comment: @AynurSibagatullin да. https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone. С другой стороны у вас серверсайд рендеринг планируется судя по тому что Вы используете, поэтому смысла в этом нет, все равно нужна штука которая этот бабель запустит. Это необязательно вебпак, но обычно он.